# Get full path of a file open using chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I want to know if there's any way to get the full path of a fileEntry using the `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`. I've tried to use `chrome.fileSystem.getFullPath` but it returns a null string.
What should I do to get the full path of a fileEntry?

Thanks

Comment: `chrome.fileSystem` is only available for chrome apps. Can you edit the question and change the wrong tag to `google-chrome-app`?

Comment: Sure! Do you have any answer to this question?

Comment: FIxed, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc page doesn't list `chrome.fileSystem.getFullPath`, only  [chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-getDisplayPath):

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile', accepts: accepts}, function(entry) {
    if (!entry) {
      console.log("Cancelled");
      return;
    }
    // All of Chrome API is asynchronous! Use callbacks:
    chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(entry, function(path) {
        console.log(path);
        // do something with path
    });
}
```

There's a great collection of chrome apps showcasing API usage on github: [chrome-app-samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples).

P.S. [The MDN article for `fileEntry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Entry) mentions `.fullPath` property but it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I've tried fullpath already, the main problem now is that fullpath only gives me \filename and not the full path. I was expecting something like c:\folder\...\filename. How to get the path just like c:\folder\...\filename? Thanks!

Comment: I've used `getDisplayPath` and it returned me `undefined`. am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you did :-) it's asynchronous as ALL of the chrome API so you need to use a callback and utilize the passed parameter in that callback (see the updated answer).

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help, I  have no experience with chrome apps or Javascript, for this reason it was kinda hard for me.

Comment: Just a final question. It seems to give me the relative system path. There's any way to get the full one? The current path is just like ~\Desktop\file. How to get the full path?

Comment: It gives a full path on Windows here. I don't have a Mac so you'll need to find an answer yourself (if it already exists) or ask a new one: "How to expand ~ home folder to the actual path on OS X in a chrome app" or something.

Comment: But actually you're not supposed to be able to access another user's folder anyway so why not just leave `~`?

Comment: Thanks for your final answer, this also will work, I don't need to use the full path! Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, just tried choosing a file from the user folder on Windows and it also is something like `~/Documents/something.css`

Comment: Entry.fullPath does work, just not for this use case.